# DisplayMemberPath not working with direct items?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, listbox, itemssource

I have a `ListBox` (or a `ComboBox`, I've tried both) where the items are added directly through `ListBoxItem` (`ComboBoxItem`) elements.

The data are `CultureInfo` objects coming from two `ObjectDataProvider` resources in the element (or in some place above). The `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo` static method is called.

In a word, I would like to have a `ListBox/ComboBox` populated with some `CultureInfo` entries.

The data binding works fine, but on setting `DisplayMemberPath` to one of the `CultureInfo` properties (such as [`DisplayName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.displayname?view=netframework-4.8) - I would like "English" to be displayed, not "en-US") nothing happens.
Oddly, if I try with `ComboBox` and select one of the items, `DisplayMemberPath` works on the selected value (which is shown in the text box), but not on the dropdown list.

My question is: am I missing something? Or does `DisplayMemberPath` not work with direct items and only when `ItemsSource` is bound to a collection (just a guess)?

```
<ListBox x:Name="LangListBox" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="EngCultureInfoProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type Globalization:CultureInfo}" MethodName="GetCultureInfo">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <System:String>en-US</System:String>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ItaCultureInfoProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type Globalization:CultureInfo}" MethodName="GetCultureInfo">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <System:String>it-IT</System:String>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource EngCultureInfoProvider}}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItaCultureInfoProvider}}"/>
</ListBox>
```

[image: ListBox]

[image: ComboBox]

Note: using ItemTemplate does not work either.

```
...
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently each ListBoxItem displays result of `ToString()` method on `CultureInfo` object.

`DisplayMemberPath` and `ItemTemplate` don't work for items, because `ListBoxItem` are added directly, not created by `ListBox`.

Add `DisplayName` in binding path:

```
<ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource EngCultureInfoProvider}, Path=DisplayName}"/>
<ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItaCultureInfoProvider}, Path=DisplayName}"/>
```

or

create default Style for ListBoxItem with custom ContentTemplate:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LangListBox" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Globalization:CultureInfo}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource EngCultureInfoProvider}}"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItaCultureInfoProvider}}"/>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thank you.

I am going to accept your answer for the second solution, because the first one is changing the item's nature and I need them to remain `CultureInfo` objects.

It seems that I'll also have to add `DisplayMemberPath` in the `ComboBox` case (to display the selected item correctly), but that's fine.